# youtube in firefox not showing part of the video and full screen and theater mode icons

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, firefox, video, chromium

i had this problem for 2 months maybe now i use to ignore it but i said to myself why not find a solution so my problem is with firefox when ever i play a youtube video it cuts part of the video image and the full screen and theater mode icons as shown in the pictures but if i go full screen then exit the full screen it goes back to normal

here you can see what i am talking about some of the icons are not showing and it cuts part of the video image too
[image: here you can see what i am talking about some of the icons are not showing and it cuts part of the video image too]

here i double click the video to go full screen to make the icons appear again and fix the video image
[image: here i double click the video to go full screen to make the icons appear again and fix the video image]

when i come out of full screen everything goes back to normal
[image: when i come out of full screen everything goes back to normal]

and i uninstalled firefox and installed it again and the problem is still there so if you can help me i hope you do and thank you .

Comment: Just for reference, I viewed the video with no issues in Firefox 52 (old - last ESR version before Quantum broke almost all the add-ons I use) and in Vivaldi 2.0.x (chromium-based). Until you find a real fix, just use another browser for problem sites. No one browser gets every dysfunctionally coded website right. There's even an Open in Vivaldi add-on for  Firefox. I'm a Vivaldi fan in case you can't tell. ;)

Comment: Also, you can ask the community at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=38